# Battery is not charging despite SMC reset

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a problem with charging of my Battery which has been appeared last night. It was working perfectly well for a long time. All of my friends who had different laptops were so jealous at my Macbook, because their laptops must have been plugged-in mostly to function well. I am worried that may laptop may being like theirs.

---

*This is the case:*
The battery is not fully charged. So, I plugged the charger to the power source, but the magasafe LED  is green and only says `Battry is not charging`. I have tried to reset SMC (I hope I did it properly), but the problem still exist. 
Here is the battery status that you may find it helpful to assist me.

Thanks for sharing your knowledge

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem Solved**
The battery was fine and the problem was with the charger. It seems that the charger couldnt transmit enough power to charge the computer while it was in use.
I opened the casing of the charger and observed that 2 capacitors were swelled. I changed them with new ones (I found them in a video receiver). 
Now its working like the first day I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Status says 'Check Battery'.
Looks like time for a new one, maybe?

Potential cycle count for that machine is 1000, & you're pretty near that figure.

*Source:* [Mac notebooks: Determining battery cycle count](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585)

Comment: So sad, It was working perfect till last night. Is there any way I can fix it? @Tetsujin

Comment: If the battery is removable on that model, you could try [with it switched off] removing, checking connections, put it back. Or, has been known to work, turn the magsafe connector the other way up & make sure it's properly seated… & clean

Comment: It is not removable, But sometimes after few minutes the status is changed to charging so the magsafe LED turns to red, but then it goes to not charging and green, So wired. @Tetsujin .

Comment: I'd go see a Genius; while they're testing it they can decide if it's connectivity/PSU or a dead battery.

Comment: I am an Electrical Engineer and have some friend in Electronic field. If I find a instruction, we can handle this.Do you have anything in your mind? @Tetsujin

Comment: You probably grok the underlying issue better than me, then, tbh, my background is sound engineer, rather than actual electronics;) I'd find a takeapart - maybe in here - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUDCBjnm6Ge1JoM5jt4M0iRw & see if everything reads the same on a meter as the Mac thinks it does, plus standard grubby connections checks etc.

Comment: @Electricman: You might find some useful tutorials on iFixit.com; otherwise, the advice to take the system to the Genius Bar is ideal. It's the usual 'no user serviceable parts' business here. Given the duty cycles the battery has seen, I would suspect battery failure.

Comment: PS - That 'Power Adapter: (null) Watts' looks to be highly suspect.

Comment: HOW Can I check if the problem is for the power adapter? also, Sometimes after a long time, the battery is charged with the adapter. @TraneFrancks

Comment: @Electricman: I'd be inclined to run diagnostics on the laptop itself. If the Apple Hardware Test comes up roses, it would suggest that there is a failure happening in the charger. A Genius Bar visit or authorized repair centre would be warranted then. My daughter's Air wouldn't charge a couple of months ago. The tech at the Genius Bar tested the MBA and when it passed, he just gave me a new AC adapter without even testing the old one. The MBA is covered under APP, so if your system isn't warrantied, you'll probably have to pay for a replacement.

Comment: Very interesting. @TraneFrancks

Comment: @Electricman: I'm not sure where coconutBattery is getting its power adapter information. If it's getting it from the battery, it still could be a battery failure (hence, check battery status). On my MacBook with a 'good' battery, my power adapter is showing as 60 Watts as expected. The hardware test should give you the information you require.

Answer (score 0):

Either you're using your laptop heavily or you need to upgrade your charger with higher power (e.g. from 65Watt to 85Watt) so it can charge faster.

This usually happens when you take/borrow charger from other MacBook Air and you'll try to charge your MacBook Pro (which could have Core i7 instead of i5).

You can click on Battery icon to see which apps are taking the most power usage.

[image: Screenshot of Battery Icon on OSX - Apps Using Significant Energy]

Comment: The problem was with  2 capacitors in the charger, I changed them and now its working fine.@kenorb