# How to get MacBook Pro(early 2011,13 inches) logic board schematic?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, logicboard

I destroyed my laptop i.e. Macbook pro early 2011-13 inches, last night. The computer works fine and has 50% charge left in the battery. But despite showing "Magsafe connected" on the screen it shows "Battery is not charging". So I went to my friend and got his charger, However, I got the same message again.

Thus, I thought its a problem with logic board. I youtubed and found something worthwhile.

At the moment I need Schematic of MacBook Pro Logic board to study the circuit and fix it.  How can I get this schematic?

Comment: give your CV to Apple and hope they'll hire you :)

Comment: Should I laugh now? @SilviuSt

Comment: Is this the same hardware with the faulty battery? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187432/i-know-my-battery-should-be-replaced-but-is-that-all-of-the-problem-update

Comment: Yes. Problem solved. It was due to sparking of an element on DC-In board. By changing the whole DC-In board, the problem has solved. Few dollars.  @bmike

Answer (score 4):

"Silviu St" tho a tad snarky is absolutely correct. Apple has not released Schematics for computers since the Apple-II days.

Apple uses state of the art PCB manufacturing and I would be willing to bet that taking a soldering iron to it or even a volt meter would be like taking a framers hammer to a dent in your car: likely to do more harm than good.

You are welcome to try but you are likely to end up with a pile of garbage worth nothing more than the alloys and rare-earths the components are made of and with.

Comment: I just opened it to measure something in the board. I found out there is a black shit under one of DC-in magsafe board. I have no clue what is it, FET,DIOD,... @steve-chambers

Comment: If I were you I would find a Mac repair shop either locally or on the internet and let them deal with it. Like I said above (unless you have experience with this) you are more likely to trash the Mac trying to fix it yourself. But then it **is** your Mac...

Answer (score 1):

ACMT here, former Apple Genius. [Everything is SMD/SMT on the boards](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology), this translates to: too small to repair or measure by hand, except you're hardcore into microelectronics and have the equipment.
For this exact reason parts like MLB (main logic board) get replaced in Apple Stores instead of 'repaired', as a skilled worker with equipment would be more expensive than replacing modules altogether.

Your best bet would be a smc-reset first, if that doesn't help try to replace the magsafe connector (under the board). Please give attention to ESD - might do more damages only by touch.

Schematics aren't available except for a few older machines, even within the company. Usually everything is Intel reference design_except_for_apple_own_stuff which you're handling here.
Your question implies you might be firm with powered devices, but not with microelectronics as the magsafe connector (who has a high chance of being faulty) has only a few caps and resistors, so...maybe you are not the right person to try this on your own, no offense.

Good luck to you

Comment: Problem solved. It was due to sparking of an element on DC-In board. By changing the whole DC-In board, the problem has solved. Few dollars.  @lolops